# Incrementally copy S3 to azure blob

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-data-factory, migrate

I am exploring ways to incrementally copy S3 blobs to azure blobs. I tried azure data factory and I was not able to find this option.

S3 has millions of objects and without an incremental option it takes hours to complete.

I am open to explore other tools/options.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to do daily/hourly incrementally copy, the [scheduled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger)/[tumbling window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-tumbling-window-trigger) trigger should be the option. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-read-write-partitioned-data#use-a-pipeline-parameter) is an example to reference. ADFv2 also supports compression in copy, you could specify the type and level of compression for the s3 object, click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#compression-support) for more information.

Comment: I am still new to data factory. It looks like to me that example is good if the files are well structured in S3 bucket. In our scenario, we don't know which folder or which file will have updates.
What I am trying to achieve is after the initial load and if we run the data factory on a schedule, we want only the changed files to be moved from AWS to Azure.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?